# Merging two sql queries into one

Tags: sql

Here is my users DB :

```
id | sex    | trending | date_registered
---+--------+----------+----------------
1  | male   | 1        | 29-04-2020
2  | male   | 1        | 28-04-2020
3  | male   | 0        | 27-04-2020
4  | female | 1        | 26-04-2020
5  | female | 1        | 25-04-2020
6  | female | 0        | 24-04-2020
7  | female | 0        | 23-04-2020
8  | male   | 1        | 22-04-2020
9  | male   | 0        | 21-04-2020
```

I want to return the users in the following orders :

1. Trending females
2. Rest of females
3. Trending males
4. Rest of males

I found a way to do it for each gender but I would like to know if there is a way to merge these two SQL queries into one :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE users.sex = 'female'
ORDER BY users.trending DESC,users.date_registered DESC

SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE users.sex = 'male'
ORDER BY users.trending DESC,users.date_registered DESC
```

So I could do something like that :

```
[my merged queries]
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: You can union these two queries too.

Comment: @Helly Yes, but that won't do anything to generate the sorting which the OP wants here.

Comment: Since, these 2 queries are already filtered on Female and Male + they are sorted too, I don't see a point to re-sort them. Since OP is looking for a way to merge these two queries I think union will be the best bet.

Comment: @Helly performing union throws an error "ORDER BY clause should come after UNION not before"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ras19AoGdPbKHGcQMZati/0).

```
select
    id,
    sex,
    trending,
    date_registered
from users
order by
    case
        when sex = 'female' and trending = 1 then 1
        when sex = 'female' and trending = 0 then 2
        when sex = 'male' and trending = 1 then 3
        when sex = 'male' and trending = 0 then 4
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified query you may use:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY sex, trending DESC;
```

This sorting logic works, because `female` comes before `male`, and a trending value of 1 comes before 0, in descending order.

Comment: thanks. I've used @zealous answer cause it seems more stable if I want to add variables.